# How do I fix this error when publishing to Nexus from Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I'm getting the error

```
Error deploying artifact 'au.com.company:library:jar': Error deploying artifact: Resource to deploy not found: File: http://nexus:8081/content/repositories/snapshots/au/com/company/library/2.1-SNAPSHOT/library-2.1-20140925.222243-1.jar does not exist
```

when publishing to Maven from Gradle with the command:

```
gradle publish
```

What could cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this was caused by an invalid URL. I had this in my build.gradle file:

```
http://nexus:8081/content/repositories/snapshots
```

and I needed this:

```
http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots
```

You have to look pretty closely at the --debug logs to see this error:

```
[DEBUG] [sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection] sun.net.www.MessageHeader@274364f26 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found}{Date: Thu, 25 Sep 2014 22:25:16 GMT}{Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store}{Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1}{Content-Length: 1370}{Server: Jetty(8.1.11.v20130520)}
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer.. and btw you can run Nexus in the root content if you want. Just add the context path in nexus.properties..

Comment: You are prevented from accepting your own answer for 2 days. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. 

"You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!"